# interleave colors on HTML table with group records from MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, colors

i've a question, I need do a intervale of two colors (gray and white) for a table on HTML with some records from a MySql table. Well, the records coming in groups by two or one, and I need to do what if coming two records with the same "ID", the  will be gray, for the next one with two records white, etc..

I've tried a lot of ways for can do this but any working yet, and for my is a complication what the records coming between two with the same "ID" and another coming for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your issue, try this:

```
<ul>
<?php $idCount = 0; $lastRowId = null;?>
<?php foreach($rows as $row):?>
    <?php if($row->id !== $lastRowId){
    //color must change
    $lastRowId = $row->id;
    $idCount++;
    }?>
    <li class="<?= $idCount%2?"white":"gray" ?>">row data here</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```